# How to properly print µ symbol on PDF with tcpdf?

Tags: pdf, utf-8, tcpdf

When I print the `µ` symbol on a PDF with TCPDF library I get a very confusing behaviour. A colleague of mine told me that the µ symbol is completely missing when he views the PDF on his computer. There is no substitute symbol or whatsoever. Simply a blank field.

The µ sign was properly printed when I opened the PDF on my computer (using FoxitPDF viewer). So to be sure I created a fresh PDF from the application to send it to him. He replied that the symbol is missing on his side again, while I can see it. I looked into my mails (gmail) and the gmail inline viewer also displays it. I opened the attached PDF in my iPhone's mail app and it ***doesn't*** show the symbol.

Notes:

- My application is using [the old TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF).
- I am using the `CourierB` font since I need a monospaced font. (I tried using `Helvetica` as a workaround on this specific character. But I still have the same behaviour.)
- I do use utf8 encoding.

Has anyone else ever had this problem? Any ideas how to overcome?